# MimeMessage alter message text

Tags: java, spring, email

I'm creating a MimeMessage using the `org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper` and want to alter the text of the email in my MailServiceImpl which uses the `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage`. At this point the MimeMessage is already fully constructed and I can't figure out a way to edit the messageText.

This is how I construct and "send" my message:

```
MimeMessage message = myMailService.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");
helper.setTo("test@test.com");
helper.setText("<h1>Hello</h1>", true);

myMailService.send(message);
```

My MailServiceImpl looks like this:

```
    @Component
    public class MyMailServiceImpl implements MyMailService {

        @Override
        public void send(MimeMessage message) {

            if (notProductionEnvironment()) {
                /* 
                at this point I want to alter the message content, something like: 
                message.setText("original receiver: " + message.getTo() + "<br />" + message.getText()); 
                */
                message.setTo(DUMMY_EMAIL);
            }
            javaMailSender.send(message);
        }
        
    }
```

Is there any way I can alter the text at this point?

Comment: Just use the `MimeMessageHelper` again and pass in the given message.

Comment: and how would I alter the text? helper.setText("altered " + ...?). Or am I missing something?

Comment: You already have that code in yuor comment. Instead of setting it on the message set it using the helper. But what I suggest you would do is instead of having that check in your service, use a different creator/service for the message creation (create the proper one depending on the `notProductionEnvironment()`). That way you abstracted all that away.

Comment: But there is nothing like message.getText() ? So my question boils down to: how to access the actual message-text within a MimeMessage.

Comment: Use `getContent` but as stated you are probably better of with 2 different message creation logics then to modify it in the service.

Comment: I have a multipart message, so getContent() only brings me this far.
Probably I'll just stick to altering my message creation logic as suggested, but I still can't believe I can't solve it this way in the service class...